# SQLite leak sem ter nenhuma classe utilizando SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, memory-leaks

Boa noite pessoal,

Estou construindo um aplicativo Android e a última coisa que preciso é montar o banco local.

Construi ele porem percebi que apareciam erros de memory leak, achei que tinha consertado mas os mesmos warnings continuavam aparecendo no console, mesmo quando **desinstalo o aplicativo do emulador e comentei todas as classes de banco de dados e seus usos** (ou seja, em nenhum lugar do meu app o SQLite é usado), aparecem os seguintes warnings:

> 04-04 23:06:12.464 2281-2291/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/metrics.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

Esse erro aparece exatamente igual para esses caras tb:

> /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/help_responses.db
>   /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/auto_complete_suggestions.db 
>   /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/metrics.db
>   /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/help_responses.db
>   /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/auto_complete_suggestions.db
>   /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/metrics.db
>   /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/help_responses.db
>   /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/auto_complete_suggestions.db

Alguma ideia de o que fazer pra remover esses leaks? Especialmente porque MESMO SEM O SQLITE eles aparecem :(

Comment: O problema parece estar na Google API e não no seu programa. De acordo com esta [resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39736005/2556111) ir a Settings - Apps - Google Play Services - MANAGE SPACE e fazer CLEAR ALL DATA resolve o problema.

Comment: @ramaral eu tinha achado essa pergunta e nao resolveu, quando rodo novamente acontece a mesma coisa :/

Comment: Veja se está a usar as versões mais recentes das Google Api's.